# Microsoft SQL Server: How to extract data from multiline field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, substring

I have a varchar column which contains something like this:

(0 or more lines of random text)

Name: John Doe

(0 or more another lines...)

I need a select query that gives me just „John Doe”. Any ideas?

In other words: I look for SQL equivalent of:
grep ”^Name:”|sed -e s/^Name://

Comment: How would you determine the end of the name? Is it always stored as `first last` or could there be instances of just `first` or `first middle last suffix`?

Comment: Just new line ends the name.

Comment: The answer below work @micha?

Comment: same question as of joe Stefanelli  how to know how long is the name ??? there is no new line in a varchar column of a table???

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines are carriage returns which is ASCII 13:

```
declare @table table (c varchar(max))

insert into @table
values
('adsfsdfdsa' + char(13) + 'Name: John Doe' + char(13) + 'adsfdsafasd'),
('Name: John Doe' + char(13) + 'adsfdsafasd'),
('adsfsdfdsa' + char(13) + 'Name: John Doe'),
('Name: John Doe')

select *
    ,WithAttribute = substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),iif(charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) = 0,99,charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99))))
    ,OnlyName = substring(
                        substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),iif(charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) = 0,99,charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99))))
                        ,6,99)
from @table
```

**USING CASE**

```
select *
    ,WithAttribute = substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),case when charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) = 0 then 99 else charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) end )
    ,OnlyName = substring(
                        substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),case when charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) = 0 then 99 else charindex(char(13),substring(c,charindex('Name:',c),99)) end )
                        ,6,99)
from @table
```

If they are something else, like line feed (ASCII 10) then just adjust the char(##) accordingly.

Comment: Sure you can use CASE statement. It’s equivalently the same. Need me to show that?

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from tablename where regexp_like(colname,'^(Name)(.*)$');
```

sql server equivalent:

```
select substr(colname,CHARINDEX('Name ',colname)+5,8) from tablename where  
PATINDEX(colname,'^(Name)(.*)$');
```

Comment: this wouldn't extract the name